# updating variables in oracle Case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I am trying to create a column that records the number of times a profession (doctor, in this case) has occurred in previous rows. Obviously, the code below does not work.

```
var row_d number
exec :row_d:=0
select case
when occupation='Doctor' then (row_d:=row_d+1)
end row_number
from occupations
;
```

Since I am new to coding, it is more important that I understand the way that Oracle handles variables in this case than that I have a piece of code that does what I am trying to do.

Ultimately, my question is: how do you update the value of variables in Oracle in general, and is there a way to do it from within a Case statement?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. SELECT selects ALL rows AT ONCE, at least in theory/in principle; there is no "successive row selection" that could even be used to increment a variable by 1 at a time. Oracle has a procedural language, PL/SQL, where you may be able to do something like that. In any case, if you speak of "previous" rows, there must be an ORDER to the rows - how are they ordered in your problem? If you want to get a running sum (ordered by a date or something), you can do that in SQL, but not the way you are trying to do it. Look up the **analytic** function `sum()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get the **result** you want. Note that there are no variables involved. SQL is a declarative language: your code describes only the result you want, the code is not made up of specific instructions telling the computer HOW to get the result you want.

I am using the EMP table in the standard SCOTT schema; you can adapt for your needs.

```
select   empno, ename, job,
         count(case when job = 'MANAGER' then 1 end) over (order by empno) mgr_running_ct
from     scott.emp
order by empno
;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB       MGR_RUNNING_CT
---------- ---------- --------- --------------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK                  0
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN               0
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN               0
      7566 JONES      MANAGER                1
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN               1
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER                2
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER                3
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST                3
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT              3
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN               3
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK                  3
      7900 JAMES      CLERK                  3
      7902 FORD       ANALYST                3
      7934 MILLER     CLERK                  3
```